# can't find executable jekyll for gem jekyll --- Jekyll Cannot be executed

Tags: jekyll

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/Suwan_Long/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    3: from /Users/Suwan_Long/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    2: from /Users/Suwan_Long/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/Suwan_Long/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:480:in `block in replace_bin_path'
/Users/Suwan_Long/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:460:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable jekyll for gem jekyll. jekyll is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
```

I have installed Jekyll and ruby, but it still shows there is no executable jekyll. Can anyone help me on this please! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 19):

The following line in the error message says it all.

```
jekyll is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
```

Edit `Gemfile` to include the `jekyll` gem:

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0"
```

Comment: Thank you I actually solved the problem but forgot to update it here. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too, Suwan.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it helped a lot. I found I could add the line using "bundle add jekyll" instead of adding it manually. Using this command it inserted the correct version number for me.

Comment: Glad to be of help, John

Comment: Is it required to run `bundle install` after editing the Gemfile?

Comment: Yes. Running `bundle install` will install the latest version satisfying the specified vesion requirements.